# PHP Mail service sends mail to everyone in loop. How to avoid that?

Tags: php, email

For my webpage, I have a php mail service which lets me send mails via

```
EmailService::getService()->sendEmail($email, $first_name, $subject, $body);
```

This works fine unless I put this line into a loop, for example to notify all listed admins:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM admin_notifications";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){      
    EmailService::getService()->sendEmail($row['email'], $row['first_name'], $subject, $body);
}
```

Right now every admin receives every mail. If there are 3 admins, for instance, every admin receives 3 different mails. The service seems to send 3 mails to each receiver each.

As I didn't implement to mails service itself and because I don't fully understand it, I don't really know where to start looking for this bug.

Maybe anyone here has suggestions?

Here is the code for the mail service:

```
<?php

    /*Verschickt Emails*/
    use TijsVerkoyen\CssToInlineStyles\CssToInlineStyles;

    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

    class EmailService{
        /**
        * instance
        *
        * Statische Variable, um die aktuelle (einzige!) Instanz dieser Klasse zu halten
        *
        * @var Singleton
        */
       protected static $_instance = null;
       protected $mail;

       /**
        * get service
        *
        * Falls die einzige Service-Instanz noch nicht existiert, erstelle sie
        * Gebe die einzige Service-Instanz dann zurück
        *
        * @return   Singleton
        */
       public static function getService()
       {
           if (null === self::$_instance)
           {
               self::$_instance = new self;
           }
           return self::$_instance;
       }

       /**
        * clone
        *
        * Kopieren der Service-Instanz von aussen ebenfalls verbieten
        */
       protected function __clone() {}

       /**
        * constructor
        *
        * externe Instanzierung verbieten
        */
       protected function __construct() {
           //new PHPMailerAutoload();
           $this->mail = new PHPMailer();

           $configs = ConfigService::getService()->getConfigs();
           $this->mail->SMTPDebug = 3;          //Gibt starke Debugging Ausgaben aus - für Realease Deaktivieren (später auf 2)
           $this->mail->setLanguage('de');
           $this->mail->IsSendmail();
           $this->mail->Host = $configs['email_host'];
           $this->mail->Port = $configs['email_port'];
           $this->mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
           $this->mail->SMTPAuth = true;
           $this->mail->Username = $configs['email_username'];
           $this->mail->Password = $configs['email_password'];
           $this->mail->From       = $configs['email_username'];
           $this->mail->FromName   = "Studienführer - VWI-ESTIEM-Karlsruhe e.V.";
           $this->mail->CharSet =  'UTF-8';
           $this->mail->isHTML(true);
       }


       /**
        * sendet Email
        *
        * Sendet eine Email an den Nutzer. Gibt ein gewisses Format vor
        */
       public function sendEmail($toEmail, $userName, $subject, $body){
           $this->mail->AddAddress($toEmail, $userName);
           $this->mail->Subject = $subject;

             $this->mail->AddEmbeddedImage(__DIR__ . '/../../pictures/logo_studi.png', 'studilogo.png', 'studilogo.png');
             $this->mail->AddEmbeddedImage(__DIR__ . '/../../pictures/email/facebook.png', 'facebook.png', 'facebook.png');
             $this->mail->AddEmbeddedImage(__DIR__ . '/../../pictures/email/instagram.png', 'instagram.png', 'instagram.png');

           $htmlWithoutCSS = '
            <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional //EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
            <html>
                <head>
                    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
                    <title>My Mail</title>
                    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
                </head>
                '.'
                <body>
                    <p>Hallo $userName,</p>
                    $body
                </body>
            </html>
            ';
           $cssToInlineStyles = new CssToInlineStyles();
           $this->mail->Body = $cssToInlineStyles->convert(
                $htmlWithoutCSS,
                file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/../../res/css/emails.css')
            );
           if(!$this->mail->Send()){
               return false;
           }else{
               return true;
           }
       }
    }

?>
```

Comment: So who should be receiving the e-mail and who shouldn't be receiving it?

Comment: What does the table `admin_notifications` consists of?

Comment: You must have some clue on how to debug? You could start with what does the database return to $row? Does that list all people three times?

Comment: Have you shown us ALL the methods in the `EmailService` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for your issue is that this line

```
$this->mail->AddAddress($toEmail, $userName);
```

adds a new email address to an list of addresses each time it is called. This is causing your to send one email to the last admin, 2 emails to the second to last admin etc etc

The `public function sendEmail($toEmail, $userName, $subject, $body){` does not appear to have been designed to be called multiple times per instantiation, but a simple change will fix the issue

Add `$mail->ClearAllRecipients();` to the method like this.

```
public function sendEmail($toEmail, $userName, $subject, $body){

    // remove previous recipients if being called multiple times in a loop
    $this->mail->ClearAllRecipients();  

    $this->mail->AddAddress($toEmail, $userName);
    $this->mail->Subject = $subject;

    . . .
```

Comment: Could there be a similar problem with `addEmbeddedImage`? Every time you call `sendEmail` it adds 3 more images (although they have the same name as previous calls -- if that's used internally as the key in an associative array, they won't multiply).

Comment: This seems to be an almost inherent problem with the use of the singleton pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the same instance each time through the loop, and every time you call `sendEmail()` it adds addresses to the instance.

You can create a new instance each time, instead of calling `getService()`, and it will start fresh.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){    
    $mailer = new EmailService;  
    $mailer->sendEmail($row['email'], $row['first_name'], $subject, $body);
}
```

Comment: As it addesses the same issue, I'm sure this would work as well, but I chose RiggsFollys solution as this will work for other people using this service, too, without telling them anything. Thanks anyways!

Comment: I agree with that. The original design didn't work well with the singleton pattern.